# Android file permission about group id

Tags: android, file, permissions

Is there a way to set multiple user ids to one group id on Android like normal Linux ?

```
crw-rw---- user1      user2    10, 251 1970-05-20 09:14 filetest
```

Currently 3 processes should access the file 'filetest' without setting others permission.

The processes have different user id.

The file is accessible from user1 process and user2 process only.

If there is a method to create group id includes user1, user2 and user3, then it's best.